# dropdown autosuggest hides list items from selection

Tags: html, css

Not able to select from auto-suggest drop-down list items after first 3/4 items. because it is hided by table grid. 
how could we do this.? any hint ?
which css/properties i need to set for table or auto-suggest drop-down list.?

[image]

Comment: please provide backend coding of html and css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to applying z-index as follow:

```
.drop-down {
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

Comment: I agree that this is the OP's problem. But one caveat: when building a multi-layered web app, you'll want to sit down and plan out a "layer flowchart" and plot out a system of "levels" that certain elements of the site will live on. For example, if you have a "loading" modal that you want to have cover everything to prevent interaction with the page, you'd want that to have the highest z-index. Other less important features you'll want to have a lower z-index.